# How is this simplication of the characteristic equation derived?

Tags: calculus, integration, calculus-of-variations

The characteristic equation in the calculus of variations (at least that's what my book calls it) is $$\frac {\partial F}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=0$$ where $F=F(x,y,y')$ in general.

My book says that in the case that $F$ does not explicitly depend on $x$ that this simplifies to $$F-\frac {dy}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=c$$

Clearly they've integrated here (or else I'm not understand how the constant $c$ was obtained), but how do you integrate $\int \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}dy$?

Comment: They haven't integrated (in the sense you are thinking), otherwise you would have

$$\int \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} dy - \int \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} dy = F - \int \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} dy \ne F - \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}$$

Did you want the proof?

Comment: Yeah.  If you could prove that these two expressions are in fact the same that'd be great.

Comment: They aren't the same expression.. Are you sure your book says if F doesn't depend on $x$ and not if F doesn't depend on a _dependent variable_?

Comment: It sums up after stating it as "Theorem: the integral $\int_a^b F(y,y')dx$, whose end points are fixed, is stationary for weak variations if $y$ satisfies the DE $$F-y'\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=c$$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant."

Comment: Also, it handles the case where $F=F(x,y')$ after that as well (that is where $F$ doesn't depend on $y$), so yeah, I'm sure.

Comment: The case where $y=0$ gives the result you stated in your original post.. That is why I asked you to make sure you didn't read the question incorrectly. So now I'm confused about what your text has given you. What book are you using?

Comment: Charles Fox's book.  I have found that this is called the Beltrami identity and am trying to go through [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_identity) proof right now.

Comment: I see, it seems to be the same proof that I was going to give for the $y=0$ case.